# Manipulating background of Card results in weird color bug

Tags: android, material-design, android-jetpack-compose

I want to manipulate the alpha value of the color that is used as the background of a Card when the type of the data is different (for example: text vs date string in screenshot below).

```
Card(
   backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary.copy(
      alpha = if (text == "Now") 1f else 0.5f
   ),
   shape = RoundedCornerShape(6.dp)
) { ... }
```

Why is there this weird darker space around the card content?

[image]

It is only visible when running the app on the emulator, the previews look fine.
It's fine when I reduce `elevation` to `0.dp`. But what if I need the elevation?

Comment: That's Android's material shadow glitch. The easiest thing to do is to avoid it by using only opaque backgrounds, or by disabling the shadow by zeroing the elevation. If you really do need a translucent/transparent background and the shadow, just without that artifact, it'll take some sort of workaround, AFAIK.

Comment: Ah, good to know. Guess I'll just have to live without the elevation then :D

Comment: As explained by Mike use `elevation = 0.dp` in your `Card` or convert your color with something like `backgroundColor = androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme.colors.primary.copy(alpha = if (text == "Now") 1f else 1.0f ).compositeOver(Color.White)`